Etymology: Division Algorithm
There is a well-known theorem about the existence of a quotient and remainder over the integers; in Elementary Number Theory by Jones and Jones, it is given as:

If $a$ and $b$ are integers with $b>0$, then there is a unique pair of integers $q$ and $r$ such that
$$ a = qb + r \quad \textrm{and} \quad 0 \leq r < b $$

This theorem is then referred to in the text as the division algorithm.  This is a common name for this theorem, even though it does not describe an algorithm, but rather just a result.  (That is, it does not appear to be merely a convention of Jones and Jones.)
Why, then, did we start calling this result "the division algorithm?"  I'm particularly curious if this naming was present when languages other than English were the predominant mode of discussing mathematics.  (For example, would Gauss have called this the divisio algorithmus, or whatever the proper Latin translation was?)
There are two non-answers or incomplete answers that I have found in trying to sift through this:

"It's named after Al-Khwārizmī and evolved into what we have today" --- I saw someone claim this on Reddit, but cannot find any source for this claim at all.
"It's named the division algorithm because the proof uses an algorithm" --- this is what Wikipedia claims, but no citation is given or indication of how long this terminology has been around.

I can see going back at least until the 1940s that there were claims of a result being true "by applying the division algorithm," but that's not quite the same as calling the theorem itself "the division algorithm."
To justify that this is a common misnomer, consider the following examples of the same type of language being used:

Lecture notes from Boise State using the misnomer
Lecture notes from UW claiming it is a common misnomer
Lecture notes from OK State using the misnomer
Wikipedia on Euclidean Division claiming "The theorem is frequently referred to as the division algorithm (although it is a theorem and not an algorithm)"
Course notes from Emory using the misnomer
Lecture notes from FSU using the misnomer
No link, but Theorem 2.10 of Elements of Modern Algebra by Gilbert uses the same presentation as above and labels the theorem "The Division Algorithm"
No link, but Dummit and Foote uses the same labeling in section 0.2 as the fifth "property of the integers" that is used without proof.


Re "This is a common name for this theorem, even though it does not describe an algorithm" By what metric / evidence is this misnomer "common"? I am seeing it here for the first time. You are quite right that this is not an algorithm, commonly defined as a step-by-step procedure. I have worked on division algorithms in a professional capacity: A theorem does not an algorithm make. Have you contacted the authors, pointing out the error / incredibly sloppy use of language? If so, what justification did they provide?

Is this not in Euclid?  Given two numbers, repeatedly subtract the smaller from the larger, until ...

@njuffa I've added some attempt at a justification that this is a common labeling of the theorem to the question body.  It was also something that my algebra prof this semester made a specific callout in lecture about (i.e. "people call this the division algorithm commonly, but I prefer to refer to it as the division theorem"), but that obviously can't be verifiably cited.

@GeraldEdgar I believe you're referring to Book VII Prop 1, the proof of which describes the Euclidean Algorithm for computing the GCD of two numbers.  Now, I believe the "Division Algorithm" theorem is easily shown as an extension of that GCD algorithm, but what I'm curious about is when people started calling the theorem/result itself (and not just the list of steps) "the division algorithm."

@apnorton Are there any indications that the cited lecture notes pertain to classes that specifically rely on Jones & Jones Elementary Number Theory? Best I can tell this book has been around since the 1990s and may have "infected" any number of people with this sloppy usage. FWIW, given the recent vintage of the book, I am temporarily withholding an upvote because I am debating with myself whether this properly belong to the history of mathematics (I think the revised question as such is OK).

At the very least, I can pre-date Jones & Jones (orig. pub. 1998) with the article Will the Real Division Algorithm Please Stand Up? by Tom Bates and Leo Rousseau (1986) which refers to the theorem above as "the division algorithm."  I'll see if I can find anything pre-20th century.

Google Ngram shows that even the expression "division algorithm" itself  is recent, it does not pick up until late 1920s. Curtiss refers to "division algorithm" for polynomials ambiguously back in 1918:"Another proof rests on the division algorithm; if $p$ is a positive real root, the quotient polynomial resulting from division of $f(x)$ by $x - p$ has at least one less variation of sign than $f(x)$."
